# Unsupported operation: Infinity or NaN toInt StreamBuilder

Tags: flutter, dart, stream-builder

I'm getting an error :

The following UnsupportedError was thrown building StreamBuilder(dirty, dependencies: [_LocalizationsScope-[GlobalKey#7d7fa], _InheritedTheme], state: _StreamBuilderBaseState<bool, AsyncSnapshot>#75e11):
Unsupported operation: Infinity or NaN toInt

from:

```
StreamBuilder<bool>(
        stream: controller.loading.stream,
        initialData: controller.loading.value,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          return GridView.count(
            crossAxisCount: 7,
            mainAxisSpacing: 5,
            crossAxisSpacing: 5,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
            children: List.generate(days, (index) {
              if (index < whiteSpaces) {
                return SizedBox.shrink();
              }

              final day = (snapshot.data! == false)
                  ? controller.getDay(
                      DateTime(year, month, index - whiteSpaces + 1))
                  : null;

              return AnimatedContainer(
                  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: (day != null)
                          ? Color.lerp(
                              Theme.of(context).shadowColor,
                              Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                              controller.countHabitsDone(day) /
                                  day.habits.length)
                          : Theme.of(context).shadowColor,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)));
            }),
          );
        }),
```

anyone can help me solve this error?

Comment: point out the error on the code. couldn't tell where it is failing

Comment: You need to check this value controller.countHabitsDone(day) / day.habits.length  this may be root cause.